# Eclipse- Source Not Found

Tags: java, eclipse

I am doing Stanford Java Class (the art and science of java), working on the exciese of implemetation of class. When I try to run the code below, Eclipse gave the error: Source not found - the souce attachment does not contain the source for the file Program.class. You can change the source attachemnt by clicking Change Attached Source below.
My current location is /ACMStarterProject/acm.jar

If you know how to resolve this, please let me know. Thanks.

```
public class Employee extends ConsoleProgram {
public void run() {
    Employee emp = new Employee("John Smith", "Robert Cook", 78000);
    println(emp.getName() + ", " + emp.getSupervisor() + ", " + emp.getSalary());
}

/**
* Creates a new employee object, which has name, supervisor’s name,
* and salary as its state. 
* @param empName The name of the employee
* @param supName The name of the supervisor
* @param sal The salary of the employee
*/

public Employee(String empName, String supName, double sal) {
    name = empName;
    supervisor = supName;
    salary = sal;
}

/**
* Returns the name of the employee.
* @return The name of the employee
*/
public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

/**
* Returns the name of the supervisor of the employee.
* @return The name of the supervisor of the employee
*/
public String getSupervisor() {
    return this.supervisor;
}

/**
* Returns the salary of the employee.
* @return The salary of the employee
*/
public double getSalary() {
    return this.salary;
}

/**
* Set the salary of the employee.
* @param sal The new salary of the employee
*/
public void setSalary(double sal) {
    this.salary = sal;
}   

/**
* Set the supervisor of the employee.
* @param supName The new salary of the employee
*/
public void setSupervisor(String supName) {
    this.supervisor = supName;    
}   

/* Private instance variables */ 
private String name;
private String supervisor;
private double salary;
}
```

Comment: How are you running your code?  You should have included this is in the question.

Comment: in Eclipse. the first few lines in the code is ;                                                         /*
* File: Employee. java
* -----------------------
* 
*/
import acm.program.*;
/**
* This class represents a simple implementation of employee.
* The client can use methods get to retrieve the employee’s name and 
* supervisor’s name.
* The client can use methods set to change the employee’s salary. 
* 
*/

Answer (score 0):

Usually you need a zip or jar file as well which contains java source code files. For example , if you want to see the source code of jre, you need something like src.zip and you need point your class to that zip file.

In your case , I guess you need something like acm.src.zip or acm.src.jar. if you find it you need point your class to this zip or jar file by selecting the right position of the corresponding file.

The jar file is similar as a zip file which bundles all the java source files(not class)  together.

Comment: I am new to java and eclipse. In the Project exploer window, there is acm.jar, and Employee.java & Employee.class are under it. And I copy source code from the text book and ran another program called 'Rational', it worked okay.